# Easy solution to make voip call from server to iOS app

Tags: ios, twilio, call, voip, callkit

I'm looking for the simplest way to make a VOIP call from a server to an iOS app that deliver a short audio message when the user answers.
I think its doable with Twilio but I am not sure.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Twilio Programmable Voice SDK for iOS. You can start with the Quickstart.

[Programmable Voice SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk)

Comment: Thank you, it's what I thought but did not want to start something I could not finish; It's all working now